What does "calidad standard" on a food item evoke?
I'm German and don't know Spanish. I bought a chocolate "Nestlé extrafin Dinosaurus Turron" originally for sale in Spain (in a store offering cheap surplus stock, sometimes imported). One corner of the front of the packaging has the phrase "calidad standard". Google translates that as standard quality.
Now, the latter does not sound very enticing to me. Transposed straight to German it would suggest an ordinary or a solid but unremarkable quality. Surely Nestlé feel no need to stress they're not substandard.
Searching for just the original phrase, in quotes, yields some hits that are actually about standards in the sense of a normative document or specification; some that indeed seem to imply ordinaryness ("acero inoxidable standard"); and some that ought to mean something more, similar to my chocolate.
What does calidad standard communicate here? Is it something like assured, trusted, proven quality?

It conveys that its quality is comparable to that of the standard of reference, assuming there’s such. But in a chocolate, made by Nestle, it’s debatable.

It refers to the type, quality or quantity of the product's ingredients. The following is an example in turrones:

La categoría se establece según el nivel de azúcares y frutos secos que contiene el turrón en este caso. A mayor cantidad de frutos secos, mayor calidad del turrón. Por esto se establecen cuatro categorías:
Calidad suprema que deben contener un 64% de frutos secos en turrones blandos y un 60% en turrones duros.
Calidad extra con un 50% de frutos secos en turrones blancos y 46% en turrones duros
Calidad Standard con 44% en turrones blancos y 40% en turrones duros
Calidad Popular que deben tener un 30% de frutos secos en turrones blancos y 34% en turrones duros.
Como vemos, solo en el mejor de los casos, el turrón suele llevar un 64% de frutos secos, por lo que para encontrar en turrón más saludable tendremos que irnos a los de calidad suprema.

Source okdiario.com
Edit after the comment
The classification of turrón is described in the BOE (Boletin Oficial del Estado) Real Decreto 1787/1982: Categoría del turrón.
Source

My chocolate was indeed with turron, I've added that in. As I said, I don't know Spanish, and I can't be sure from your source's autotranslation whether those categories are in fact defined in the Royal Decree mentioned there. Presumably so, given their presence on a package, but if you can ascertain and mention their actual origin then I'll accept.

Answer updated.-

It might be worthwhile to add a definition of Turrón to your answer for those of us who have never heard of it before.
